# Does botkit google hangouts chat in version 0.7 or google hangouts chat supporting typing indicator?

Tags: botkit, google-hangouts, botkit-middleware

Does botkit google hangouts bot in version 0.7 or google hangouts chat supporting typing indicator? as i cannot find anything in google hangouts developer document and in botkit google hangout document as well. could help share the document or give some example if it does support.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question here. Hangouts Chat supports typing indicator, but I guess you are referring to building bots that show typing indicators just before writing a message? I don't think that is possible for Hangouts Chat.

Comment: yes , I means for building bots that show typing indicators. okay thank you for your response